# What material is the holding container aboard the helicarrier made of?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers, the-avengers-2012, composition

In the Avengers movie, Thor is seen hitting the holding container (designed to contain The Hulk if I'm not mistaken) with his hammer, Mjolnir, which is made of enchanted uru. The glass (?) of the container can somewhat withstand that impact surprisingly. However, it is cracked, and the container is seen partly dislodged from its holding clamps. 
I suppose the last is why Thor stops hitting it, as he doesn't fancy a fall to the ground while inside the container/holding cell.

But what transparent material is tough enough to (mostly) withstand the impact of the incredibly massive Mjolnir ?  I'm afraid the answer will be to simply fit into the movie script, but any other insight will be appreciated.

Comment: An object is transparent, it doesn't mean its weak like ordinary glass. Today, transparent glass is available which is stronger than even steel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only material I know of that could withstand anything like that is Aluminum Oxynitride - literal transparent Aluminum, Which can withstand anti-aircraft fire.

Other candidates would be I high strength polymer of somekind. Either way withstanding strikes from mjolnir is not impossible, at least for a short while.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be several materials sandwiched together (think something like airplane windows which are several layers of plexiglass or Lexan) with something like a web of [Carbon Nano-Tubes or Carbyne](http://metamodern.com/2010/09/29/stronger-than-carbon-nanotubes-polyynes-and-carbyne/) similar in design to Ballistic Glass